# JQuery find() syntax not working in v 1.12

Tags: jquery, syntax, find

I have some legacy JQuery code in version 1.4.3 and i'm trying to upgrade to version 1.12.4 (before eventually upgrading to v 3.x).

However, this piece of code that used to work in 1.4 is no longer working after I upgraded to 1.12.

```
var str = $("#fav-inst-table")
.find("tr:has(td:has(input:checkbox[id^='fav_doc_'][checked]))")
```

I read over the upgrade logs and instructions and i'm not too sure what can contribute to the code not working.  I'm not too much of a JQuery expert, sorry if my question seems dumb.

The selector $("#fav-inst-table") returns the expected value just fine (in Edge debugger), it's the "find" function that no longer works with the current syntax, and returns nothing.

Comment: Your code, *as provided*, works fine in both jquery 1.4.3 *and* jquery 1.12.4.  Please provide enough code to *demonstrate* the issue.  Here's it working in 1.12.4 with the HTML that's implied: https://jsfiddle.net/678kmdp1/

Comment: hi Freedom, thank you so much for the link, i will try to clean up my code a bit and see if i can post a more complete version, meanwhile i'm playing around with your js code and indeed it is working in 1.14.  The only thing that might be messing with my code is i am also using jquery migrate 1.4.1, do you think this is somehow making my code to not work?

Comment: Your 1.4.3 code is using migrate?  So you have some older code (eg built against jq 1.3) that's using jq1.4 + migrate?)  Did you also remove migrate 1.4 when you added jq 1.12?

Comment: do you need all these `:has()` in the selector anyhow? can't you simplify it to `.find("[id^='fav_doc_'][checked]")`

Comment: my JQuery 1.4.3 was not using migrate, but i added the 1.4.1 migrate with the 1.12.4 upgrade.  From what i read, it seems like 1.4.1 migrate should be compatible with 1.12.4, should i not have used it?

Comment: @cloned that would not give a list of `tr`.  The equivalent would be `$("[id^='fav_doc_'][checked]").closest("tr")` (which would also be simpler)

Comment: freedom, would $("[id^='fav_doc_'][checked]").closest("tr") only return one TR or all of the TRs?

Comment: you are right, they are querying the `tr`; it's too early for me ;) But whatever, the point would be to simplify the whole query. [.closest()](https://api.jquery.com/closest/) would return all closest TR, just like the `.find()` query.

Comment: thanks I will try that.  I removed jquery migrate import, and it is still not working.

Comment: @TimZ `$("td").closest("tr")` will return all TRs that have a TD.  .closest is applied to each element and then combined - it's not "closest of all"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

took a while for us to finally debug the issue but it seems, even though jsfiddle says this syntax is correct for 1.12.4, our environment which runs on java JDK 1.8 does not recognize this specific syntax for some reason.

What worked for us was
var str = $("#fav-inst-table")
.find("tr:has(td:has(input:checkbox[id^='fav_doc_']:checked))")

instead of [checked] it was :checked.

If anyone has any input as to why :checked worked instead of [checked] I would appreciate the input too, in case we run into similar situation with syntax in the future.  Thanks.

Comment: `[checked]` looks for the *attribute* "checked" - ie what it was when loaded - while `:checked` looks for the *property*.  Updated fiddle to demonstrate the difference: https://jsfiddle.net/1mxw9f3b/1/

Comment: Why your "java JDK 1.8" doesn't like it is a completely different issue - that wasn't mentioned in the question.

Comment: thanks Freedomn for your explaination of [checked] vs :checked! that makes alot of sense as our check box was dynamically generated, and i'm guessing somewhere between v1.4 to 1.12, there was a syntax change that distinguished [checked] from :checked